# Convert built-in plots in high-quality graphics for publications?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I use the PUPAIM package to generate adsorption isotherms e.g. redlichpanalysis(Ce,Qe)

For example with the following variables:

```
install.packages("PUPAIM")
library(PUPAIM)
library(nls2)
Ce <- c(1.447071, 1.605402, 2.196297)
Co <- c(2,3,4)
Qe <- (Co-Ce)*100/0.33
redlichpanalysis(Ce,Qe)
#give immediately the statistics and basic plot as output format
```

This generate a plot:

[image]

How I can customize the plotting procedure and get high-quality graphics that are similar to ggplot2? (the rest of my graphics is made in ggplot 2. so that is the reason why I am emphasize this issue).

I searched for similar questions and found e.g. ggplotify package. Frankly speaking, I don't really understand it. If I change the plot object in ggplot object so how I can customize it. I tried for example to add "theme_bw()", but it fails.

I need to rescale the axis, add a layout similar to theme_bw(), add axis labels with proper units and probably also adjust the style of the measurement points as well as the regression itself.

Thank a lot for any suggestions on how I can customize the given basic built-in plots...

Comment: @BenBolker: I edit the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we review the [source code](https://rdrr.io/cran/PUPAIM/src/R/redlichpetersonanalysis.R) for `PUPAIM::redlichpanalysis`, we will see that the plotting is simple:

```
redlichpanalysis <- function(Ce, Qe){
    x <- Ce
    y <- Qe
    data <- data.frame(x, y)
    n<- nrow(na.omit(data))
    print("NLS2 Analysis for Redlich Peterson Isotherm Model")
    fit257 <- (Qe ~ (Arp*Ce)/(1+(Krp*(Ce^b))))
    start <- data.frame(Arp = c(1, 100), Krp = c(1, 100), b = c(0, 1))
    set.seed(511)
    fit258 <- nls2(fit257, start = start, control = nls.control(maxiter = 50, warnOnly = TRUE), algorithm = "port")
#<removed irrelevant lines here>
    plot(x, y, main = "Redlich Peterson Isotherm", xlab = "Ce", ylab = "Qe")
    lines(x, predict(fit258), col = "black")
#<more irrelevant lines here>
}
```

We can do the same thing with `ggplot`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(PUPAIM)

startfit <- (Qe ~ (Arp*Ce)/(1+(Krp*(Ce^b))))
start <- data.frame(Arp = c(1, 100), Krp = c(1, 100), b = c(0, 1))
set.seed(511)
endfit <- nls2(startfit, start = start, control = nls.control(maxiter = 50, warnOnly = TRUE), algorithm = "port")
predict(endfit)

data.frame(Ce,Qe,Predict = predict(endfit)) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=Ce, y = Qe)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line(aes(y = Predict)) +
  ggtitle("Redlich Peterson Isotherm") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: but this doesn't show the predicted values, which are presumably the main point (and which are hard to extract from the function results, based on the way it is implemented. My advice would actually be to copy the *entire* code into your own function, return the predicted values, and go from there ...

Comment: Thank you Ian! I assume, it is the best way to work with a source code as you proposed.

Comment: You could suggest to the maintainer how much more useful the package would be if it were slightly more modular ...